# Disabling trackpad on Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

How do I disable my mouse trackpad on a Lenovo notebook running Windows 7?

Usually Lenovo installs with tools which allows you to do so (Ultranav). However, this laptop has a modified image installed specifically for my organization and the mouse is showing as a generic PS/2 driver.

How can I disable the trackpad? It is quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to disable the trackpad through Device Manager.

1. Open Computer Management: Start -> Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Device Manager. You require administrator privileges to open Device Manager.
2. In Device Manager, expand **Mice and other pointing devices**
3. The trackpad will either appear as something relevant to trackpads (like IBM Trackpad) or a generic mouse. Double click the entry (or right click -> Properties)
4. Click the **Driver** tab.
5. Click **Disable**. Click **OK**. Close Device Manager

The trackpad should now be disabled.

Alternatively, if you have administrator rights, you could [download](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS019164) and install Ultranav

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to your BIOS then to "config" tab -> keyboard/mouste -> set Touch Pad to disabled.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to "Control Panel" --> "Mouse" --> tab "UltraNav", click "Show UltraNav icon on the system tray".
2. Go to system tray, click "UltraNav", click "Disable/Enable".

Answer (score 1):

I have found the easiest method since the TouchPad+TrackPoint driver adds a tab to Control Panel's "Mouse" configuration applet:

Control Panel > Mouse > ThinkPad tab > Pointing Options > Use TrackPoint Only

Comment: Worked for Ultrabook and Windows 10. Seems to be the most easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the device in the BIOS.

***Most ThinkPad Models use the ENTER Key at boot prior to post then F1 or just F1, F12 then choose TAB to get to setup or scroll down to system setup depending on your bios version***

Under `Config` > `Keyboard / mouse`> `Track Pad` = `Disabled`.

Track Point is the red nubby thing that is rarely used and rarely gets in the way of any typing functions. Then it is off and will not be discovered by the system at any time.

I generally leave the Track Point enabled as users like to have something quick to use in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

As a seasoned (read, "aged") Thinkpad user - I love the "red nubby thing"!  (I had one of the very first Thinkpads and will buy nothing else.  On my - I think - 5th model).

Hit Fn and F8 then the second option to disable the Toughpad (aka trackpad).

Comment: On ThinkPad W541 Fn+F5 combination opens wireless radio on/off dialog.